# Windows 10 starting at 98% CPU Usage: How to troubleshoot this?

Tags: windows-10, memory, cpu

Most of the times when I boot into my Windows 10 Home 64-bit on my laptop, I experience a strange phenomenon. The only operation I would be able to perform is to bring up the task manager and see some weird numbers - like CPU usage at 98%, Memory 0 MB and so on.

**CPU Usage:** Note that it's in descending order

[image]

**Performance Screen**

[image]

**Startup:** After going through some forums, I felt it's the Synaptics driver which is causing issues and therefore, I completely disabled it (I don't use touchpad)

[image]

While I can initiate a restart or shutdown of the PC using Alt + F4 from the desktop, the operation never ends and I need to do a hard power off. After a couple of hard reboots, things start working fine. It's a dual-boot laptop and Ubuntu runs perfect.

How to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Install the WPT (part of the Win10 SDK: https://dev.windows.com/en-us/downloads/windows-10-sdk), run WPRUI.exe, select "First Level", under  Resource select **CPU usage** and click on **start**. Now capture 1 minute of the CPU usage. After 1 minute click on **Save**. Zip the large ETL file (+ NGENPDB folder) into 1 zip, upload the zip (OneDrive, dropbox, google drive) and post the share link here.

Comment: If you use Autoruns and force the driver NOT to load when a user is logged into, does the behavior exhibit itself, if not then have you updated the Synaptics driver to a version that specifically supports Windows 10?

Comment: @Ramhound, Synaptics driver was up-to-date. I can say this since it used to get installed (Windows 10 driver Update took care of it) even if I uninstalled it. That's when I decided to disable it. @ magicandre1981, I am not sure how I can run WPRUI when the machine does not respond. I can run it when it responds and post it.

Comment: run it before you see the issue and stop it after Windows response again.

Comment: @magicandre1981 that's not going to happen since Windows stops responding immediately after turning it on - as soon as the desktop appears. Anyway, after 3 days, today the issue didn't arise. I will wait for a day or two and close this question.

Comment: in scenario select "boot" and 1 iteration. This reboots the PC and captures 2 minutes CPU usage after boot. This should include the CPU usage you see after boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I have found the solution. Between reboots, I realized that the issue outlined above did not occur when the ethernet cable was not plugged. Therefore, just before checking if there were driver issues on that front, I chose to examine the Event Logs. The system log was filled with errors and warnings, predominantly 7001 which stated Event ID: 7001

> The Net.Tcp Listener Adapter service depends on the Net.Tcp Port
>   Sharing Service service which failed to start because of the following
>   error:  The service cannot be started, either because it is disabled
>   or because it has no enabled devices associated with it.

Searching around on the web, I discovered this solution which worked.

> Alternatively, go to Control Panel, open Optional Features, and under
>   .NET 4.6 expand and under WCF (expanded), uncheck the entry related to
>   Net.Tcp Listener Adapter service, then click OK, Event id 7001 is
>   solved too. Reboot. [Source](http://www.tenforums.com/performance-maintenance/20707-windows-10-boot-hanging-welcome-screen-event-id-7001-a-post374748.html#post374748)

I went a step ahead and chose to disable IIS since I don't need it and that took care of the rest i.e., TCP under WCF services. Frankly speaking, I don't really remember when / why I enabled IIS. My thorough searches (since I was armed with event IDs) pointed to the fact that many people who updated from Windows 7 to Windows 10 faced similar issues. Though I had updated to Windows 10 on the launch date, I hardly used it and, therefore, ignored the issues till now.

Other warnings which I took care of [was 7031](http://www.tenforums.com/general-support/13521-anyone-know-how-fix-event-id-7031-a-post538137.html#post538137). I also deleted Windows AntiMalware and Media Center (verify before deleting, exact names may vary) tasks from the event scheduler since they were trying to use non-existent executables.

**Edit**
After I posted the above answer, some freezing issues continued to appear. Having realized that Event Viewer can be a friend in my troubleshooting exercise, I worked towards eliminating every issue that came. I have just published the entire experience as a [blog post](http://www.staygeo.com/2016/03/troubleshooting-constantly-freezing.html).

Comment: @magicandre1981 further there were some issues which continued to cause the freezes. I worked towards solving them and also published a blog post (added a link by editing the answer).